# Java - Parsing unformatted string

Tags: java

I have an unformatted string like this:

```
Tabs,[
{ tab1 = {
   Title = tab1name
 }
}
{ tab2 = {
   Title = tab2name
 }
}
{ tab3 = {
   Title = tab3name
 }
}
]
```

I need to parse this string and i need the **title** from it.
Is there is any other way to do like json parsing ?

Any help please.

Comment: What have you done till now? Show some code.

Comment: I just used split but i thought its a complex process.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, provide more info on efforts you made and share some code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear - are you trying to parse source code or are you trying to parse the elements within the Tab[] object? If you're looking into this for a serious project, I'd recommend looking into something like cup. If it's something simpler and you merely need specific information from a collection of strings, you can use a variety of string methods. For instance -

replace()

split()

substring()

toUpperCase()

etc...

You can find more on this documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html), I'd recommend it for a good read that might help you answer this and future questions.